# SWD Debug Using U-Link Pro for STM32 Device

Tags: stm32, debugging, swd

I want to debug my stm32f429 device using U-Link Pro in Keil. I applied the required connections for that and when I try to SWD debug in Keil I receive below "Communication Failure" error. How can I fix that ? I've shared the photos of my setup and the error. I've tried every "Max Clock" Settings. Thank you in advance...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi again, when i connect my ulink pro with my PC via USB, there is no 3.3V difference between VCC and GND on my 20-pin connector and there is just 0.3V difference. Can the problem related with that reason ?